# Best Practices For Splitting Payments

Tags: openzeppelin, smart-contract-wallets, payments

I have bulid a payment split flow. It is working and tested on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/). I am using [PaymentSplitter by OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol) and here's how it looks overall:

[image]

However, I would really appreciate if I can get a second opinion on:

- If this is the correct way to go?
- Can I simplify this more in anyway?
- Do I need to consider and what could be the gas charges for each transactional flow?
- Any other pitfalls?

Any help is much appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi SyedAliTaqi! Welcome to Ethereum StackExchange! Honestly with only a diagram it is hard to recommend anything, there are just boxes in a diagram. Probably you should reach an auditing firm for them to analyze the contracts relationships.